# Play sound parallel

Tags: c++, windows, soundplayer

How can I play sound parallel in c++?
I tried it with the PlaySound function of the Windows Api and Threads, but when a sound starts playing in another Thread, the sound from the other Threads stopped.
Is there any way to get two different sounds to be played at the same time?

Comment: You can mix the two sounds (or any number of sounds) yourself and play the result using Windows' waveOut API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FModEx](http://www.fmod.org/download/), Luke.

Now seriously, FMod is a very easy-to-use sound library. Go to the linked page and download FMOD Ex Programmer’s API. Since it's quite mature library, you'll be able to find [many examples](http://devmaster.net/posts/2862/introduction-to-c-with-game-development-part-20-sound) and tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: Just for curiosity.. have you try FMod on linux?

Comment: No, I did not. Actually, I used only C# wrapper for FMod on Windows (though the original libraries are for C++, of course).